# CodeIgniter - how to prevent PHP Notices from being displayed?

Tags: codeigniter

I've inherited a CodeIgniter project which is displaying PHP notice errors all over the place. I've tried to alter the logging level to prevent them from appearing, but they're still showing.

Here's how I'm setting the logging level in index.php;

```
// I Have confirmed that the value of ENVIRONMENT is 'development'
define('ENVIRONMENT', !empty(getenv('CI_ENV')) ? getenv('CI_ENV') : 'production');

switch (ENVIRONMENT) {
    case 'development':
        ini_set('display_errors', 1);
        ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
        error_reporting(E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE & ~E_STRICT);
        break;

    case 'testing':
    case 'production':
        ini_set('display_errors', 0);
        if (version_compare(PHP_VERSION, '5.3', '>=')) {
            error_reporting(E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE & ~E_DEPRECATED & ~E_STRICT & ~E_USER_NOTICE & ~E_USER_DEPRECATED);
        } else {
            error_reporting(E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE & ~E_STRICT & ~E_USER_NOTICE);
        }
        break;

    default:
        header('HTTP/1.1 503 Service Unavailable.', TRUE, 503);
        echo 'The application environment is not set correctly.';
        exit(1); // EXIT_ERROR
}
```

Comment: Is this on a Live site (production) or on a development site? Can you find out what CI_ENV is set to? You can simply override the Environment Define to be production if required but personally I'd be going in and fixing up the errors/notices and warnings etc.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're on development env. Try the below.

```
ini_set('display_errors', 0);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 0);
```

Perhaps also set the CI log threshold to 0

goto

> application/config/config.php

```
$config['log_threshold'] = 0;
```

Comment: Yes I am on development environment. I want errors to show, but I don't want to see notices, they're not critical errors.

Comment: ohh.. in that case, your code looks like it should work

Comment: Perhaps you can try the OR condition. error_reporting(E_ALL & ~(E_STRICT | E_NOTICE ))